# How to restore cluster configuration containing static regions and dynamic regions without data

Tags: apache, geode

I have a cluster that has 2 locators 2 servers with some static regions.

In disaster mode when the whole cluster is down and I want my clients (JAVA and c++) ones to reconnect automatically when the cluster is up.
Taking into account the fact that we use continuous query and listeners on regions.

The symptome is when we restart the cluster with the same cluster configuration on the same ports the static region is created but the dynamic region are not created and the cluster fails to recreate the cluster correclty.

The client that uses continuous query and listener hangs indefinitely.

I can make the client code resilient if at least all regions are created correctly without any data.

P.S: We use this code to create dynamic regions
https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/region_options/dynamic_region_creation.html

Answer (score 1):

The cluster configuration service contains all configuration elements that have been persisted to it, either manually through the API or using GFSH commands. The "problem" with the example shown in [Creating Regions Dynamically](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/developing/region_options/dynamic_region_creation.html) is that it doesn't persist the changes within the cluster configuration service and, as such, the region is not automatically restored when the cluster starts up again.

In order to persist the changes, you need use the new [ConfigurationPersistenceService](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/distributed/ConfigurationPersistenceService.java), keep in mind that the feature is currently marked as experimental so it might be subject to changes. For example usage and a detailed explanation, please have a look at [Configuration Persistence Service](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Configuration+Persistence+Service). As a side note, this service is used by almost all GFSH commands, you might want to have a look at [CommandExecutor](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/remote/CommandExecutor.java#L185-L205) for more details.

Hope this helps. Cheers.